# Объясните как передаются данные из View в Controller

Tags: c#, mvc

Допустим пример:

View:

```
<form method="post" action="~/Home/Area">
    <label>Высота:</label><br />
    <input type="number" name="height" /><br />
    <label>Основание:</label><br />
    <input type="number" name="altitude" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public string Area(Geometry geometry)
        {
            return $"Площадь треугольника с основанием {geometry.Altitude} и высотой {geometry.Height} равна {geometry.GetArea()}";
        }
```

Класс Geometry:

```
public class Geometry
{
    public int Altitude { get; set; } // основание
    public int Height { get; set; } // высота

    public double GetArea() // вычисление площади треугольника
    {
        return Altitude * Height / 2;
    }
}
```

Собственно в чем сам вопрос. Каким образом когда я передаю 2 переменные из view (altitude и height) они преобразуются в объект класса Geometry. Ведь метод ожидает объект Geometry, а не две переменные.

Comment: "altitude" и "height" это одно и то же.

Comment: В каком смысле одно и то же? Они же хранят разные данные.

Comment: Эти слова значат примерно одно и то же.